# Having problem with calling function. C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, console-application

I wrote a SetInterval and SetTimeOut Function as JavaScript function, but I can't set low 100 millisecond and also I can't call two SetInterval. Please Help Me!

Including

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;

milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
    );
```

SetTimeOut with Parameter Function

```
 template <typename Proc, typename T>
    void SetTimeOut(T & val, Proc p, unsigned long long n) {
        unsigned long long def = ms.count(); // starting point
        unsigned long long ds = ms.count() + n; // the time what need become equal to def
    
        while (def != ds) {
            milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
                ); // time updates
            def = ms.count(); // converting to nums
    
        }
        p(val); // calling the main function
    }
```

Same, but calling unparameter function

```
template <typename Proc>
void SetTimeOut(Proc p, unsigned long long n) {
    unsigned long long def = ms.count() ;
    unsigned long long ds = ms.count() + n;
    while (def != ds) {
        milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
            system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ); // time updates
        def = ms.count();
    }
    p(); // Main function calling
}
```

p - the function that we want call, n - how much time should pass, s - how many times should be repeated.
SetInterval with unparameter function

```
template <typename Proc>
void SetInterval(Proc p, unsigned long long n, long long s) {
    //here there are call in turn of function SetTimeOut
    for (int i = 1; i != s + 1; i++) SetTimeOut(p, n * i);
}
//Same, but for parameter function
template <typename T, typename Proc>
void SetInterval(T val, Proc p, unsigned long long n, long long s) { 
    for(int i = 1; i != s+1; i++) SetTimeOut(val, p, n * i);

}
 //Example with struct
  struct Car{
    string model;
    double speed;
    int fuel;
};
```

Main Function

```
int main() {
    Car Car;
    int i = 1;
    Car.fuel = 200;
    Car.speed = 10.2;
    
    //Example with lambda function.
    SetInterval(Car,[&](struct Car){
        Car.speed += 1.9;
        Car.fuel -= 1.2;
        cout << Car.speed << " " << Car.fuel << endl;
        }, 900, 10); // it will end after 10 calls with 0.9 sec interval
     //Second Example, which is not working
    SetInterval(i, [&](int i){ i++; cout << i << endl;}, 500, 5);
}
```

I think it because call time crosses, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: why question is marked for `c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
    while (def != ds) {
        milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
            system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ); // time updates
        def = ms.count(); // converting to nums

    }
    p(val); // calling the main function
```

This's a spin loop.  It will just peg an entire CPU core while constantly checking to see "is it time yet".  At the very least, put a sleep statement there and check for `<=` instead of `!=` in case your clock jumps ahead.

```
    while (def <= ds) {

        duration<milliseconds> tosleepfor(ds-def);
        this_thread::sleep_for(tosleepfor);

        milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(
            system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ); // time updates
        def = ms.count(); // converting to nums

    }
    p(val); // calling the main function
```

But here's the fundamental problem with your design.  Javascript has a built in message pump for doing asynchronous work - including setting timers with callbacks.  C++ doesn't have such a facility.  Your `SetTimeout` function doesn't actually set a timeout.  It just stalls the program until the time has been reached.

You have to make use of your OS's GUI thread or have your own concept of message pumping to dispatch callbacks at specific intervals.

Comment: I'm just learning programming. I did it for fun, but thanks for the advice